# How I can apply a network_security_config.xml on specific variants and not in release one?

Tags: android, gradle

In my build.gradle I have the follwing `buildTypes`:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            //debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_DOMAIN", "\"api.example.com\""
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_DOMAIN", "\"api.local\""
        }

        staging {
            initWith debug
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_DOMAIN", "\"https://api.staging.example.com\""
        }
}
```

Also the `api.local` I use self-signed certificates that I configure them into the `network-security-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <!-- local -->
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.local</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/api"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
    <!-- /local -->
</network-security-config>
```

Also, in `app/src/main/res/raw` I place a file named `api.crt` where it is the self-signed certificate.

But once wither I build a `release` or a `staging` variant I do not want the certificates to be shipped. Is there a way to do so? Also how I can specify per-variant `network-security.xml`

One way is to use a CI/CD pipeline and delete the certificates whilst I replace the `network-security-config.xml` with a default one before I run:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Or

```
./gradlew assembleStaging
```

But this approach may not scale if app needs to be built in my (coleagues) local machine at any variant. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different resource for each build type or variant. When adding a new resource, you can select the appropriate source set. For example, in the attached screenshot I am adding an element for the debug build variant. You can add different configs for different variants, different flavors or combination of variant and flavor. So, just add an empty config for the prod/staging and have the debug variant use the network config you want.

[image]

What this does is basically add the resource in the appropriate folder in the structure. When building, Gradle will override the more-generic resources with more specific ones (if you have a resource in the main folder and you specify a resource for a flavor with the same name, the flavor resource will override the main one)

Comment: So for specific flavours I'll need to create the folders `src/debug/res` and `src/staging/res` where inside the `raw` and `xml` folders where the `network-security-config.xml` and the `certificates` will reside. Right?

Comment: Correct. Specify a default one in the main resources, and for every flavor/build type you want to override, add a specific resource folder. Use the IDE to avoid mistakes in the file structure

Answer (score 0):

For Do such specific changes you have to create the flavour for `release`, `debug` and `staging` and then you can create a different-different folder for each folder whether it would be for resource or java.

Inside that flavour resource folder, you may put the specific file so that changes will affect those flavours only.

Hope you get my point, due to time urgency I couldn't post the example.

Comment: Well I'll love an example either as a link OR if you update the post and place it later.